# Local HTML5 video playback with MP4/WebM Blob chunks

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm looking for the way to play relatively large (up to 500mb) MP4/WebM by means of HTML5 video. The complication is that the video isn't available as URL or file but as a sequence of `Blob`s.

The app is primarily oriented at desktop (Chrome) and mobile (Android/iOS Webview) offline usage. There's no ability to stream the video locally, I'm counting entirely on client-side JS (no native platform extensions).

The video is stored in resource container (storage implementation is out of scope of the question) and can't be loaded at once because of its size, but it can be retrieved and buffered as several `Blob` chunks.

It would be more convenient to read chunks from unparted MP4/WebM instead of splitting it, but I guess that this approach requires a local streaming server.

It is possible to split the video into smaller clips (~10Mb) beforehand if this is necessary, but they should be played seamlessly.

An approach I've initially tried looks like that

```
var player = document.querySelector('video');

getBlob('webm-chunk1')
.then(function (chunk1) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(chunk1); 
  player.src = url;
  player.play();

  return getBlob('webm-chunk2');
})
.then(function (chunk2) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(chunk2); 

  player.addEventListener('ended', handler, false);

  function handler() {
    player.removeEventListener('ended', handler);

    player.src = url;
    player.load();
    player.play();
  }
});
```

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9IPNgjHunNzBbENY9eBT?p=info) that demonstrates it, currently works in Chrome. There is problem with seamless playback, a gap between two chunks is noticeable. Even if there are two `<video>` that are switched on `ended` event, ~100ms gap is still there.

How can a sequence of progressively loading `Blob`s be played as seamless HTML5 video?

Comment: Have a look at this article that uses the MediaSource api http://wwwhtml5rockscom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tutorials/streaming/multimedia/en/